# Indicate wrong type variable declaration

Tags: javascript, types, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

Can Visual Studio code see errors (or point out to warning) when setting variable of different type than the one indicated in `@typedef` of jsdoc?

I am declaring a `@typedef` with a property of type "number". I want to know if Visual Studio code can (with help of some extension or else) indicate that there is a potential problem there. I do not want to use TypeScript and any npm compiler because it is an older project written in vanilla Javascript.

```
/** Simple object
* @typedef {Object} SimpleObject
* @prop {number} id
*/

/**
 * @type {SimpleObject}
 */
let testObject;

// Can Visual Studio Code indicate that warning about setting different type // here
testObject.id = "TEST"
```

When I hover mouse over id property, I get information that it's type should be number but no signs of warning are placed, even though I explicitly placed a "string" type value upon it.

Comment: testObject.id = "TEST"  // Can this throw error of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found that you can add

//@ts-check

at the begining of a file to fore type checking on jsdoc